# If $y''+f(y')=0$ why is $y(x)=\int_1^x g^{-1}(c_1-\tau)d\tau + c_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this differential equation:

$y''+f(y')=0$

WolframAlpha gives, for almost every choice of unusual function $f$ I've been able to think of, the following solution:

$y(x)=\int_1^x g^{-1}(c_1-\tau)d\tau + c_2$

where $g(t)=\int_1^t \frac{1}{f(t)} dt$

Using $f(t) = \tanh(t)$ this is definitely true, but is this true for every choice of $\frac{1}{f}$ which has an inverse? Where did WolframAlpha come up with this equation? I'm struggling to find the right words to search for more information about this method and WolframAlpha doesn't explain how it came to this solution.

Comment: Let $z=y'$ and use an integrating factor.

Comment: The above suggestion is certainly how one would find this representation. To check its validity, note that it implies $y'(x)=g^{-1}(c_1-x)$ and therefore 
$$g(y'(x))=c_1-x=\int_1^{y'(x)}\frac{dt}{f(t)}.$$
Differentiating once more yields $-1=y''(x)\cdot 1/f(y'(x))$ which is equivalent to the original ODE.